# how I solve it: this.options = options ?? {}; in mongoDB

Tags: node.js

[image: Why does this error appear, and how do I solve it?]

When I put my code to connect to the database, I get this error.
But when I enter the same code in another project, it works.
How do I solve this problem.

Comment: You could easily put the text from the screenshot as text here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) is not supported in older versions of Node.js.

Check your current node version with `node -v` (Terminal/cmd) or `console.log(process.version);` (in Node.js). It has to be at least `14.0.0` (but ideally the newest). If not, check, if you can upgrade to the latest LTS version.